# Is there a sparse version of tf.multiply?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Does Tensorflow has a sparse element wise multiplication?
I.e. A sparse version of tf.multiply()

I only found tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(), but it's not element wise multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

The function you might be looking for is: [__mul__](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensor#__mul__)

Additional details from official documentation:

The output locations corresponding to the implicitly zero elements in the sparse tensor **will be zero** (i.e., will not take up storage space), regardless of the contents of the dense tensor (even if it's +/-INF and that INF*0 == NaN).

**Limitation**: this Op only broadcasts the dense side to the sparse side, but not the other direction.

Example:

```
sp_mat = tf.SparseTensor([[0,0],[0,2],[1,2],[2,1]], np.ones(4), [3,3])
const1 = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], dtype=tf.float64)
const2 = tf.constant(np.array([1,2,3]),dtype=tf.float64)

elementwise_result = sp_mat.__mul__(const1)
broadcast_result   = sp_mat.__mul__(const2)

print("Sparse Matrix:\n",tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(sp_mat).eval())
print("\n\nElementwise:\n",tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(elementwise_result).eval())
print("\n\nBroadcast:\n",tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(broadcast_result).eval())
```

Output:

```
Sparse Matrix:
 [[ 1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]]


Elementwise:
 [[ 1.  0.  3.]
 [ 0.  0.  6.]
 [ 0.  8.  0.]]


Broadcast:
 [[ 1.  0.  3.]
 [ 0.  0.  3.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.]]
```