# tensorflow: how to perform element-wise multiplication between two sparse matrix

Tags: tensorflow, sparse-matrix, multiplication, elementwise-operations

I have two sparse matrices declared using the `tf.sparse_placeholder`. I need to perform the element-wise multiplication between the two matrices. But I cannot find such an implementation in `tensorflow`. The most related function is `tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul`, but this is a function performing matrix multiplication between one sparse matrix and one dense matrix.

What I hope to find is to performing **element-wise multiplication between two sparse matrices**. Is there any implementation of this in `tensorflow`?

I show the following example of performing multiplication between dense matrices. I'm looking forward to seeing a solution.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Element-wise multiplication, two dense matrices
A = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(100, 100))
B = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(100, 100))
C = tf.multiply(A, B)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
RandA = np.random.rand(100, 100)
RandB = np.random.rand(100, 100)
print sess.run(C, feed_dict={A: RandA, B: RandB})

# matrix multiplication, A is sparse and B is dense
A = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32)
B = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(5,5))
C = tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(A, B)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
indices = np.array([[3, 2], [1, 2]], dtype=np.int64)
values = np.array([1.0, 2.0], dtype=np.float32)
shape = np.array([5,5], dtype=np.int64)
Sparse_A = tf.SparseTensorValue(indices, values, shape)
RandB = np.ones((5, 5))
print sess.run(C, feed_dict={A: Sparse_A, B: RandB})
```

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Don't have enough rep to comment but this looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810168/is-there-a-sparse-version-of-tf-multiply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorFlow currently has no sparse-sparse element-wise multiplication operation.

We don't plan to add support for this currently, but contributions are definitely welcome! Feel free to create a github issue here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new and perhaps you or someone in the community can pick it up :)

Thanks!

Comment: Do create an issue though, as someone may pick it up. Just no one on the team is actively working on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`tf.matmul`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul) or [`tf.sparse_matmul`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_matmul)for sparse matrices also; setting `a_is_sparse` and `b_is_sparse` as `True`.

```
matmul(
    a,
    b,
    transpose_a=False,
    transpose_b=False,
    adjoint_a=False,
    adjoint_b=False,
    a_is_sparse=False,
    b_is_sparse=False,
    name=None
)
```

For element-wise multiplication, one workaround is to use [`tf.sparse_to_dense`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_to_dense) for converting sparse tensor to dense representation and using `tf.multiply` for element-wise multiplication

Comment: Thx. Is this matrix multiplication or element-wise multiplication? I need element-wise multiplication.

Comment: this is matrix multiplication, not element-wise; also `tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul` is not element-wise.

Comment: OK. Then let's wait for other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from another post works.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45103767/2415428

Use the `__mul__` to perform the element-wise multiplication.

TF2.1 ref: [https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/SparseTensor#**mul**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/SparseTensor#__mul__)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Tensorflow 2.4.1.

Here's my workaround to multiply **two** sparse tensor **element-wise**:

```
def sparse_element_wise_mul(a: tf.SparseTensor, b: tf.SparseTensor):
    a_plus_b = tf.sparse.add(a, b)
    a_plus_b_square = tf.square(a_plus_b)
    minus_a_square = tf.negative(tf.square(a))
    minus_b_square = tf.negative(tf.square(b))
    _2ab = tf.sparse.add(
        tf.sparse.add(
            a_plus_b_square,
            minus_a_square
        ),
        minus_b_square
    )
    ab = tf.sparse.map_values(tf.multiply, _2ab, 0.5)
    return ab
```

Here's some simple explanation:

Given that

> (a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2a*b + b^2

we can calculate a*b by

> a*b = ((a+b)^2 - a^2 - b^2) / 2

It seems the gradient can be calculated correctly with such a workaround.