# Working with different Tensor types in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

I'm struggling to work with different tensor types and operations between them. For example, a basic division `tf.divide(a, b)` is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert elements of SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("inputs_8_copy:0", shape=(None, 2), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("cond/Cast_1:0", shape=(None,), dtype=float64), dense_shape=Tensor("inputs_10_copy:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int64)) to Tensor. Consider casting elements to a supported type. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes for supported TF dtypes.
```

I was able to work around this by calling `tf.sparse.to_dense` on `a` and `b`. But the approach doesn't scale when the dataset is large. Nor does it work in general because I don't know the tensor type of all of the features (I'm working within a `preprocessing_fn` in TFT and the data comes from BigQuery).

This seems like a very common issue that should have a simple answer but I'm not able to find any information on it. Something like basic divisions shouldn't cause this much trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a difficult question, in fact.
For element-wise division in particular, let say ai and bi are scalars. if ai = 0 and bi is not zero, then ai/bi = 0, but what if ai = 0 and bi = 0, ai/bi = ? 0?
Even worse, if ai is not zero and bi = 0 then ai/bi is NaN!
So if the divisor is a sparse tensor, it will raise (possibly lots of) NaNs, unless the indices of both sparse matrices are the same. Same problem if you divide a dense matrix by a sparse matrix.

There is a nice a workaround to multiply two sparse tensors element-wise [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731484/tensorflow-how-to-perform-element-wise-multiplication-between-two-sparse-matrix), based on the relation (a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2 ab.
It is also possible to compute the inverse of a sparse tensor C: `tf.SparseTensor(indices=C.indices, values=1/C.values, dense_shape=C.dense_shape)`.

So there is this NaN issue for division, and concerning the mixture of dense tensor and sparse tensor, one option consists in converting the sparse tensor to a dense tensor. But we want to avoid this. In the other direction, from converting the dense tensor to a sparse tensor, this can be very ineffective if the tensor is not *really* sparse.

All this to say that it does not seem to be a simple problem.

Comment: I was looking for more of a templated workflow solution but I guess the question is too generic. Thank you for the help regardless.

Comment: How expensive is it to compute the inverse as you suggestion as compared to converting this to dense tensor?